# Many to Many relationship Laravel with different Values, products attributes

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to create the products Attributes with a many to many relationship but i have a problem with the attribute Value. For instance:

`Product->belongsToMany(App\Attribute)`
`Attribute->belongsToMany(App\Product)`

Now i need the attribute to be 'Color' and i want that Color to be "Red" and take it from another table.

So i can't figure out how to create this relatioship.

`Product->attributes->Color->red.`

In fact if i do it this way it works but of course all products will take that atttribute value 'red', so all products are going to be red which is not correct.

The simple way i tried and of course worked fine is without a pivot table and a simple relation.
Just added a column in the product table with the attribute name and value but doing that way it will convert my product table in a giant table with a lot of attributes inside, ex:

`'name', 'description', 'price', 'color', 'size', 'warranty' and so on with too many attributes which is really unoptimized`

The expected result is to have multiple attributes for a product and those attributes to have multiple values for different products. 
Hope someone can solve this relational problem or enlighten me. Than you anyway.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do something similar to Wordpress taxonomy, no?
If so your Attribute table would have only two fields "name" and "value. 
name = 'color'
value = 'red'
Then getting $product->attributes would return sort of a list of name/value pairs. You would have to create your own helpers/functions on the product to get the specified attribute like "color" if it exists for the specified product

Answer (score 0):

Model Product

```
public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id');
    }
```

Model Arrribute

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_attributes', 'attribute_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

Code

```
$product = new Product();
$attributes = $product->attributes;
$productWithAttributes = $product->with('attributes')->get();
```